# What is the prediction function for sequence of images to be predicted as 'Good'/'Bad' by CNN+LSTM(many to one) classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

My input shape to the model is (None,90,112,112,3) none takes the value of samples, 90 is the number of images in each sample that is nothing but sequence length, and 112,112,3 are the image dimensions. I have trained CNN+LSTM model meaning first it will extract the features of all 90 images and then passes these to LSTM all the way to produce binary classification as to 'good'(1) or 'bad'(0)

```
 model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',activation = 'relu'),
                              input_shape = (SEQUENCE_LENGTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, num_channels)))
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))) 
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.7)))
    #model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.7)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.7)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.7)))
    #model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
                                      
    model.add(LSTM(28))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    model.summary()
```

My training is successful with accuracy around 89%.
but in real-time prediction, what should be my prediction function to classify for the a set images.
I tried with below code.

```
for incident in sequences_now: # loop over the sorted list of images
  for index in incident:
    a=index['path_name'] # pull out the path to read it those images
    print(a)
    size=(112,112) #set the size of the image to read
    img = load_img(a, color_mode = "rgb", target_size=size, interpolation='bilinear')
    image_array = img_to_array(img) 
    normalized_img = image_array/255  #Normalise the image array vaules between 0's and 1's
    image_reader.append(image_array)
  ni=len(image_reader)
  predictor =np.array(image_reader)
    # Pass the normalized frames to the model and get the predicted probability.
  predicted_label_probability = LRCN_model.predict(predictor,batch_size=ni)
  predicted_label = np.round(abs(predicted_label_probability))
  if predicted_label == 1:
      print("Good Incident")
  if predicted_label == 0:
      print("Bad Incident")
```

This is giving the error as,

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 90, 112, 112, 3), found shape=(69, 112, 112, 3)

1. Whether the prediction function written is correct?, if not what changes is needed?
2. Meanwhile the sequence length varies during real-time so what code do I need to change to make predictions if I am having variable sequence length?
3. Do I need to train my model also using variable sequence length? If I have to do that what I need to change in the model input section?

Comment: on the one hand you ask "What is the prediction function..." but then you present a `ValueError`... which is it? please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Prediction function is not working properly, for which that was the error

Comment: You need to store the shape which is 69 in a variable. None will not be acceptable by the function as it opposes the definition. Introduce a variable x and mention the shape as (x,90,112,3)